# Does the "this" keyword inside a constructor refer to the name of the instance of the class?

Tags: javascript

Does the `this` keyword inside a constructor refer to the name of the instance of the class that is being create. Does it refer to person1 in this example?

```
function Person(name,age){
     this.name = name;
     this.age = age;
}

const person1 = new Person('ana', '13');
```

Comment: sort of, it refers to the instance being created, not the variable that holds it .... i.e. you could write JUST `new Person('ana', '13')` and `this` still refers to the new instance even though it's not being assigned to anything

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```js
let thisStored = null;
function Person(name,age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    thisStored = this;
}

const person1 = new Person('ana', '13');
console.log(person1 === thisStored); // output: true
```